# How to call next element using structure array in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct abc
    {
      int a;
      float b;
      char c;
      double d;
    };
    int i;

    struct abc s[4] = {{1, 2, 3},
                       {2, 3, 4},
                       {3, 4, 5},
                       {4, 5, 6}};

    printf("a = %p\n", s[1]);
    printf("a + 1 = %p\n", s[i]+1);


}
```

error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘struct abc’ and ‘int’)

Comment: I assume your actual code assigns a value to variable `i` because in the code you posted in your question, I don't see where `i` is assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

> error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘struct abc’ and ‘int’)

That's because `s[i]` is a struct (`abc`). You can't add a structure to an `int`. What you want to access is the next structure of that array, which you can do via `s[i + 1]`

There are a few other issues with your code.

- your initialisation code is incorrect `{1, 2, 3}` - the struct has 4 members but you initialised only 3 - need to provide one more number.
- it's not necessary to provide the array size `4` as the compiler can work it out by your initialisation code.
- your `printf` is also incorrect: `printf("a = %p\n", s[1]);` - you can't print the whole struct that way. If you want to print just member `a` of the first struct, then use `printf("a = %d\n", s[1].a);` Otherwise if the intention is to print the address, then you need  `printf("a = %p\n", &s[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

1. Your struct has 4 members; you instantiated it like it has 3.
2. `printf("a = %p\n", s[1]);`
   You are accesing the element at the index 1 of the array. That is also wrong as your array is of `struct abc` type.

   From what I'm seeing you're trying to print the address of the specific element, you could do that using pointer arithmetics:

   `printf("%p",(s+i));` or using & to specify that you want the address of that element: `printf("%p",&s[i]);`
3. Also, you declared your `i` without giving it a value, so it will have some `garbage value` your computer has in its ram. It is good practice to always declare and initialize your variables when you write code:
   `int i = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

The error says 'invalid operands to binary + (have ‘struct abc’ and ‘int’)' which means you are trying to add integer to a structure. We can access array elements by using indices. For example s[0], s[1] ...

if s is array of integers, then s[0], s[1] ... each represents integers. In your program, s is array of struct abc, so s[0], s[1] ... each represents struct abc.

There are some issues in your program like below.

- i is uninitialized. s[i + 1] is invalid
- s[1] represents struct abc. It is not address. If you want to print
  the address, you need to use &s[1]
- struct abc has 4 variables. But your array is only initializing 3
  parameters

Below is the program.

```
int main()
{
    struct abc
    {
      int a;
      float b;
      char c;
      double d;
    };

    int i;

    struct abc s[4] = {{1, 2, 'a', 3},
                       {2, 3, 'b', 4},
                       {3, 4, 'c', 5},
                       {4, 5, 'd', 6}};

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("a = %p\n", &s[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("a + 1 = %p\n", s[i+1]);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This is a user specific scenario. That's why I just come to the point. I accept your valuable comment, next time I will take care of this. For this , here is a well explained accepted answer. So I just leave it.